# Is there any abbreviation to actual word conversion feature in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I'm new to NLTK/NLP, I want to know is there a option to get the text transformation as given below. Input is **pwr** and Output is **power**

```
pwr => power 
tmp => temprature
pres => pressure
```

I'm able to achieve this by replacing the text(pwr) with the actual word(power).
Do python nltk have such capability? Thanks

Comment: It should be straightforward, even if not immediately available in NLTK. 1) Define a transformation function that takes an abbreviation and returns its expansion. 2) Tokenize your data. 3) Apply the transformation to each token.